# How to get the Property of an Object in PHP

Tags: php, laravel

I have an object that looks like this and has a `This is a demo Variable` property I want to access.

[image: Screenshot of PHP Object]

---

I have the object saved in a variable called `kpi`:

```
$kpi = new Kpi($item);
```

And now I want to access the variable, but doing the following returns `null`:

```
dd($kpi->demoVariable) // null
```

How do I access the properties I set in my constructor?

For reference, here is the constructor function:

```
public function __construct(Fuelconsumption $item)
{
    $this->demoVariable = 'This is a demo Variable';
}
```

---

Edit:

I guess I would need to assign the properties to the `attributes` array, since it seems like laravel gets access to this array, by the above stated commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just:

```
$kpi['demoVariable'];
```

Instead of

```
$kpi->demoVariable;
```